# What happens if you transfer ether and no miner is running?

Tags: transactions, mining, private-blockchain

What happen if I transfer ether from account a to account b on a private chain with just one node and that node is not mining?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The transaction will simply sit in the txpool until a miner picks it up and includes it in a block.

If there is nobody mining, the blockchain will simply not produce any more blocks and thus not process any transactions.

Additionaly, miners can find and produce blocks *without* including transactions, if desired.

Answer (score 6):

Your question should not be:

> What happens if I transfer ether from account a to account b

But:

> What happens if I send a transaction to transfer ether from account a to account b

What happens? Well, the transaction remains in the transaction pool and does not become part of the chain. 
So the Ethers are not transferred.